# python indexing, writing vals where match

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am new to python, and I am looking for a way to programatically index and assign values to a dataframe where certain where certain columns match.

I am currently doing this in Excel with this function in "C2" and each cell in column C to the last row, "=INDEX(B:B,MATCH(1,(T:T=T2)*(Y:Y=Y2)*(Z:Z=Z2)*(A:A<>A2),0))"` array.

This looks through the all referenced columns and finds the first match where each of these conditions is true. This works well with small data sets, but with larger data (30k rows, 65 cols) and greater it is really slow, and I am trying to move away from excel in general.

I have tried a `for` loop on a `pandas df`, but this took even longer than excel!

```
for i in range(len(sep_data)):
  if sep_data['C'][i]=="": # This is optional, but some of these fields are already populated and if so I wanted to skip the following code for those lines
    for j in range(len(sep_data)):
        if i != j:
            if sep_data['ColT'][i] == sep_data['ColT'][j] and \
                sep_data['ColY'][i] == sep_data['ColY'][j] and \
                sep_data['Z'][i] == sep_data['Z'][j] and \
                sep_data['A'][i] != sep_data['A'][j]:
                    sep_data['C'][i] = sep_data['B'][j]
                    sep_data['C'][j] = sep_data['B'][i]
```

Is there a more elegant and efficient way to accomplish this?

I am assuming that `pandas df` is the best way to manage the data in python, but is there some other package more suited to what I am trying to do?

Thanks!

Comment: Please add an example here of an input and the expected output from that. I think only then will this make sense. You suggest an array formula in Excel, but `ColC2 "=Index(ColB,Match(1,(ColT = T2)*(ColY = Y2)*(ColZ = Z2)*(ColA <> A2),0))"` is not correct syntax as far as I can tell, and I cannot make the jump to how it relates to your Python code. `if sep_data['C'][i]=="":` is particularly confusing, at least to me.

Answer (score 0):

For this particular instance we can simplify part of the if statement that you have using some pythonic language. The first step is you need to create a list with all the values of the columns that you want to check for equality, like such:

```
equal_cols = ["ColT", "ColY", "Z"]
```

And then in your loop you want to add after the line `if i<>j:`.

```
for i in range(len(sep_data)):
  if sep_data['C'][i]=="":
    for j in range(len(sep_data)):
        if i <> j:
            check_equal = [sep_data[col][i] == sep_data[col][j] for col in equal_cols]
            if False not in check_equal and sep_data['A'][i] != sep_data['A'][j]:
```

That list will create a list of boolean values and then you check to see that False is not in it (meaning all values are true) and if that is true then go to your next step.

Comment: I really think there is a proper `pandas` answer to this. This answer sidesteps all the built-in functionality that will make it faster than `Excel` by miles.

Comment: I agree with you, but I am not familiar enough with the pandas documentation at this point to be able to break it apart and apply it!

Comment: @User9123 can you give a 10-line example showing exactly what you're trying to do? i.e. input and output. I have to be honest, I've used Excel for years and `ColC2` means nothing to me; is that the actual formula? You say "array" at the end; it's an array formula?

Comment: ColC2 is "C2", Column C, cell 2. The combination of the index and match functions is an array function in excel. In my formula where it simply says ColA, that would be a named range in my worksheet, or alternatively "A:A"

Comment: @User9123 That's why I made my comment on the main question. If you use invalid syntax and, based on your explanation there, what do we make of `ColA <> A2`?

Comment: I replaced the column references with "A:A" in the excel formula. This does actually work in Excel and returns the correct result. It is an array formula, so you have to hit control + shift + enter for it to work correctly. I am looking for the other row where corresponding cells in each column match for all columns EXCEPT column A, which should not match A2